# Symfony 1.4. How to add attributes of fields to the embedded form?

Tags: symfony-1.4, embed, symfony-forms

I embed one form to another. I need to add HTML attributes to the fields embedded form.
Trying to do so:

```
$this->widgetschema['email'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('class' => 'email'));
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it this way? 
creating a class

```
 class YourForm extends sfForm {
     $array= array('array');
     $this->setWidgets(array(
          'field1' => new sfWidgetFormSelect(array('choices' => $array), array('placeholder' => 'field1', 'required' => 'true', 'data-empty' => 'U did not enter field1!')),
          'email_address' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array('type' => 'email'), array())
     ));   
 }
```

You can even change the type in the first array. Then include your form in the actions by calling it like

```
 $this->form = new YourForm();
```

Then echo your form in the template:

```
 <?php echo $form; ?>
```

I hope this helps. I use it like this as well, to add extra attributes to use in javascript.